# Undefined integration bounds after U substitution

Tags: calculus

I am given the gamma integral defined as:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{b-1} *exp(-a*x)dx = a^{-b}*\Gamma(b) $$

To solve the integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp\left(\frac{-k}{y}\right)}{y^{2.5}}dy $$

In order to make the equations similar I applied u-substitution such as:

$$ u = \frac{1}{y} $$ $$ du = -\frac{1}{y^{2}}dy $$ 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp\left(\frac{-k}{y}\right)}{y^{2.5}}dy 
=  \int_{uhh}^{umm} u^{0.5-1}exp(-uk)du $$

So how do I deal with the bounds? Normally I would plug them into y and solve for u but in this case I'd get $ 1/0 $ and $ 1/\infty $.

Can I just use the limits as x approaches $ 0 $ and $ \infty $ for $ 1/x $?
Leading to:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{exp\left(\frac{-k}{y}\right)}{y^{2.5}}dy 
=  \int_{\infty}^{0} u^{0.5-1}exp(-uk)du $$

Comment: Start with $y = 1/x, dy = \frac{-dx}{x^2}, \quad \int_0^\infty f(1/y) dy = \int_\infty^0 f(x) \frac{-dx}{x^2}=\int_0^\infty f(x) \frac{dx}{x^2}$ where I used $\int_0^\infty = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^{1/a}, \lim_{a \to 0^+} 1/a = \infty, \lim_{a \to 0^+} 1/(1/a) = 0$

Comment: $-ax=-\dfrac{k}{y}$ then $y=\dfrac{k}{ax}$